# How to include an external logic app implementation in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

### Separation infra and workflow

I have deployed multiple logic apps in azure using ARM templates. This means that the entire workflow of these apps has been defined in the deployment templates, which clutters up these files. I'd like to keep the implementation of the workflow separated from the definition of the infrastucture.

The implementation of one logic app already takes up ~200 lines in the ARM template:

```
6     "resources": [
            (...)
535         {
536           "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
537           "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
538           "name": "NotifyKubernetesUpgrades",
539           "location": "West Europe",
540           "identity": {
541             "type": "SystemAssigned"
542           },
543           "properties": {
544             "state": "Enabled",
545             "definition": {

                   (*...implementation of the workflow...*)

724             }
725           }
726        },
```

#### What I'd like to achieve:

Have a `/src/workflows` folder with the json workflows. 
Import workflow into the ARM template at the implementation of the workflow).

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't. A logic app is exactly that: *an arm template*.

Comment: Yes I understand, that's why I think the following should be possible. 

I'd like to start these arm templates in a `/workflows` directory and include them using a `-  template /workflows/logicapp1` statement or something similar.

Comment: are you familiar with how to integrate logic apps into a devops pipeline?

Comment: Usually the workflow is specified  where `(*...definition of the workflow...*)` is mentioned in the snippet above, right?